# How to use Delphi code within Java Project?

Tags: java, delphi

I have an old yet very complicated algorithm written in the Delphi Programming Language that I want to use as a service for a Java project.

My plan is to build a site that can serve the algorithms benefits through a web interface without re-writing the code due to it's complicity.

I have seen many options for doing the exact opposite (that make sense) but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your Delphi code directly in a Java process, you would have to put the Delphi code into a DLL and then use JNI/JNA or ActiveX/COM to access that DLL in your Java code.  Otherwise, move the Delphi code to a separate process and have your Java process communicate with it as needed.

Comment: I interpreted the question more as how to convert Delphi code to Java. Then again, it's not very clear what is meant by "use delphi code in java".

Comment: Considering the algorithm is "very complicated", I read the question as not wanting to port the code to Java (and potentially breaking it), but rather to use the original Delphi code as-is.

Comment: Web services would be another way. COM would be another way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is what i was looking for, in order not to re-write the code

Answer (score 0):

I use the same through a Mormot server: https://synopse.info/
It allow me to execute procedures and get results (in binary or json for example) along side of others cool things...

Or you cam use TIdHttpServer, and call your old procedures like an webservice, like mormot but vastly more restricted